# Jenkinsからgitサーバーへssh(パスワード認証)したい

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

使用したいgitサーバーがssh(パスワード認証)になっているのですが、
Jenkinsの認証情報の追加設定は「sshユーザー名と秘密鍵」となっています。

sshでユーザー名、パスワードによる認証をしたいのですがどのようにすれば可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`expect` でパスワード入力を自動化するスクリプトを書けばできると思います。

スクリプト例

```
#!/bin/sh
USER=$1
HOSTNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
PROMPT=$4
COMMAND=$5

expect -c "
set timeout 60
spawn ssh ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}
expect \"password:\"
send \"${PASSWORD}\n\"
expect \"${PROMPT}\"
send \"${COMMAND}\n\"
expect \"${PROMPT}\"
send \"exit\n\"
interact
"
```

実行すると次のようになります(例ではRHELサーバーにログインしてます)

```
$ ./sshtest.sh user 192.168.1.10 hogehoge '$' 'echo hello jenkins'
spawn ssh user@192.168.1.10
user@192.168.1.10's password:
Last login: Fri Aug 26 20:48:52 2016 from 172.16.100.33
[user@192.168.1.10 ~]$ echo hello jenkins
hello jenkins
[user@192.168.1.10 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.1.10 closed.
```